# 3 ft long stick is cut a 2 random points, forming 3 shorter sticks.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

What is the probability that the middle stick is <=1?

<-0--------------x-------------y--------------------3->

x and y are the two cuts.

but.... x does not have to be the first cut always, y can be.....

<-0------------y----------------x--------------3----->

so...

I got these two equations: y-x<=1,
                           x-y<=1

now what do I do?

Comment: Plot an $xy$-coordinate diagram.

Comment: I am sorry. i forgot to because I only recently got enough rep to actually vote and know I can cause I am 16 rep. now. Got to be > or = 15 to upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your two cuts are chosen uniformly and independently, then your two inequalities above give the red band below. Now find the fraction of red part inside the $3\times3$ square, over the whole square:

[image]

Comment: Which gives the same answer as above. Did claims that this is incorrect, the answer is $\frac{5}{9}$. Can you see why he thinks this?

Comment: @mtiano No this does not. The red area is 5.